# Does enabling SMB2 on a NetApp filer require a cifs restart?

Tags: server-message-block, cifs, netapp, ontap

I would like to enable SMB2 on a FAS 2050 running Data ONTAP 7.3.2 as by default it is disabled.

I have discovered that to enable SMB2 the following option must be set:

```
options cifs.smb2.enable on
```

Does this require a restart of cifs to take affect or just does it start working magically? Also will this change persist across a reboot?

Update: As per James post below the following setting allows the filer to use SMB2 when talking to other servers.

```
options cifs.smb2.client.enable on
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check na_options.

http://filer/na_admin/man/man1/na_options.1.html

> **cifs.smb2.enable** This option enables SMB 2.0 support on the Filer.
>   When this option is enabled, the Filer
>   uses SMB 2.0 with a Windows client, if
>   the client supports SMB 2.0. When this
>   option is disabled, the Filer will not
>   accept any new SMB 2.0 sessions;
>   existing sessions are not terminated.
>
> **Default**: off
>
> **Effective**: Immediately
>
> **Persistence**: Remains in effect across system reboots
>
> **cifs.smb2.client.enable** This option enables SMB 2.0 client
>   capability on the Filer. When this
>   option is enabled, Filer-initiated
>   connections to Windows servers use the
>   SMB 2.0 protocol. If the Windows
>   server does not support the SMB 2.0
>   protocol, the Filer uses SMB 1.0. If a
>   session was established over SMB 2.0
>   and then this option is disabled,
>   existing sessions are not terminated.
>   The Filer continues to use SMB 2.0 for
>   the existing sessions; new sessions do
>   not use SMB 2.0.
>
> **Default**: off
>
> **Effective**: Immediately
>
> **Persistence**: Remains in effect across system reboots